# how 2d array filter get value in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, filter, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array

```
val A = Array((10.0,1.0,2.0,3.0),(20.0,4.0,5.0,6.0),(10.0,7.2.8.0,9.0))
```

how can I filter the first element which equal to 10, and get the other element value ?

result like:

```
x = Array((1.0,2.0,3.0),(7.2.8.0,9.0))
```

and  I can use x(i) to get the value inside the array

thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
A.filter(_._1 == 10).map{case (a,b,c,d)=>(b,c,d)}
```

Or like this:

```
for ((a,b,c,d) <- A if a == 10) yield (b,c,d)
```

(By the way, it's recommended that you don't use arrays in Scala unless you really need to; you should prefer immutable collections such as Seq and Vector. There's a (somewhat old) introduction to Scala collections [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html).)

Comment: if I use the first way, how can I use the valu b,c,d ?
like : 
val x = A.filter(_._1 == 10).map{case (a,b,c,d)=>(b,c,d)}
and x(0) can get (Double, Double, Double) = (1.0,2.0,3.0)
but if I want to get the only the value "1.0" , how can I do? 
I'm a beginner of scala, so many concepts are not clear. thank you for your detailed reply :)

Comment: You can use the syntax `(1.0,2.0,3.0)._1` to get the 1st element of the tuple (in this case, 1.0). Similarly, `tuple._2` gets the 2nd element, and so on. For your example, `x(0)._1` would return 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> A.filter(_._1 == 10.0).map(t => t.productIterator.toList.tail)
res0: Array[List[Any]] = Array(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), List(7.2, 8.0, 9.0))
```